# ReadOnly queries on secondary server do not return correct values

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I have two servers A and B. Both are in an Always On Group. The B server is configured for ReadOnly requests. This works fine so far, but recently there is a problem for queries for a service.

The service first makes an update to a table (probably on the A server) and then a select with Read Only on the B server. The developer says these are two separate transactions.

Unfortunately, the select does not return the values with which an update was previously made. Only after about 1 to 1.5 seconds do the correct values appear. We have never been able to observe this behaviour before.

The server is set to synchronous commit. All databases are synchronous and have no data loss. The routing for read only has been tested and works. Readable Secondary is set to "Yes".

I've only been working as a DBA for MSSQL databases for about 1.5 years and I don't quite understand how the two nodes A and B communicate in an AG, but I assumed that both nodes would receive the data at the same time when using "synchronous commit", right?

What could be the reason for this 1 to 1.5 second time difference?

Servers are SQL 2019 Enterprise with CU12 - Running on some powerful physical machines with Windows Server 2016 Standard.

Comment: Powerful machines or not, have you looked at [resource contention on the secondary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/troubleshoot-availability-group-exceeded-rto?view=sql-server-ver16#BKMK_CONTENTION)?

Comment: FYI - the more you read from the synchronous secondary, the more likely the redo is going to be delayed even further on the secondary.

Answer (score 12):

> The service first makes an update to a table (probably on the A server) and then a select with Read Only on the B server. Unfortunately, the select does not return the values with which an update was previously made. Only after about 1 to 1.5 seconds do the correct values appear.

That's expected and how the product was designed. Commit harden (sync-commit) does not include redo, it only encompasses the harden on the secondary. Harden and Redo are two distinctly different processes for an AG in SQL Server.

> I don't quite understand how the two nodes A and B communicate in an AG, but I assumed that both nodes would receive the data at the same time when using "synchronous commit", right?

The primary is responsible for capturing the "changes" which are packed up into log records, these are in turn packed into log blocks. The log blocks are (over simplifying here) closed and flushed on a commit, which is then used to copy and send to the other replicas independently of each other. Depending on various factors, this may or may not be a speedy process as it must traverse through other layers and threads.

Eventually the log block will make it on the side of the secondary, be hardened, and depending on partner type will either immediately send a progress message or wait. When the primary receives the progress message for the specific replica that sent it, various internal values are updated, and other various checks occur. That happens for each replica, regardless of partner type (sync/async).

Thus, data is not received at the same time on all replicas, nor is there any guarantee it completed redo before the progress message is processed on the primary.

SQL Server is returning valid and correct data as per the start of the read transaction based on snapshot isolation, just not the data that is wanted/expected.

Comment: So, would there be a better method than just a "sleep()" in the code? As far as I know our devlopers using the .NET library.
The whole thing works on the production system, but not on the integration system (same hardware).

Comment: @SettusBlake The best would be to read from the primary if you require the absolute latest information based on your isolation level.

Comment: Also, how do you even guarantee that the read command is actually reaching server B AFTER the write command in server A? There's no way the two servers will communicate with each other to make sure that your write was done first before the read. You're using the synchronous commit in a way that it isn't designed for.

Comment: @Nelson I am only the DBA, not the devoloper. They use the .NET framework for communication with the database. Is there a way to check if the B Server has all the information already?

Comment: @SettusBlake Synchronous commit is not designed to do that. If you need that type of transactional guarantees, the two calls need to hit the same DBMS layer and let the DBMS layer enforce the guarantee. What's the reason for doing the write on a separate server from the read and then require a guaranteed write? The entire thing sounds really bizarre.

Comment: No reason at all. I just tell the devloper he should not use readonly Option for this.

Answer (score 8):

*Synchronous* and *No data loss* only means that the transaction log has been hardened on the Secondary replica. It has no guarantees about the Redo phase.

Hopefully, this image explains it

[image: synchronous-commit mode diagram]

Image source: [Common Causes and Troubleshooting Solutions for SQL AG Data Synchronization Latency](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/common-causes-and-troubleshooting-solutions-for-sql-ag-data/ba-p/2963083)

The log Redo on the secondary can be delayed for many reasons, the most common being that it's blocked. You can check for the Redo block in a default Extended Event **AlwaysOn_health** event *lock_redo_blocked*.

[image]

I recommend enabling the event field **Resource_description** (which is not on by default).